# upload image from CkEditor in Angular 5

Tags: angular, ckeditor, angular5

1. i am using **ngx-ckeditor: "0.4.0"** in angular 5.
2. i want to upload image to my Amazon S3 server from CkEditor, so how can i add this functionality?
3. below is my html code

   ```
   <ck-editor 
             name="html_template" 
             [(ngModel)]="mailModel.html_template" 
             [config]="ckEditorConfig">
   </ck-editor>
   ```
4. here is my component code

   ```
   this.ckEditorConfig = {
       filebrowserUploadUrl: 'http://192.168.0.107:8000/api/crm/v1.0/crm-distribution-library-files',
       fileTools_requestHeaders: {
           'X-Requested-With': 'xhr',
           Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
       },
       filebrowserUploadMethod: 'xhr',
       on: {
           instanceReady: function( evt ) {
               var editor = evt.editor;
               console.log('editor ===>', editor);
           },
           fileUploadRequest: function(evt) {
               console.log( 'evt ===>', evt );
           },
       },
   };
   ```

> **with this i am not able to get file & also not able to send custom Header**

Comment: What is the error message you get? What is the exact code of your upload logic?

Comment: @ForestG when i select file and click the button **'Send it to the Server'** call was going to the right URL, but from backend side i get error, **'No File Provided'**, & also not able to pass **'Header'**

Comment: hm.. what can you see in your browsers's Network tab then you click the upload? Is the header and the file in the request sent to the service there?

Comment: @ForestG no, only url called, but **FILES & Header** not going with that.

Comment: did you enable the File Browser and the Image uploader plugins as described here? https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/fileupload.html maybe

Comment: @ForestG yes, i enabled **File Browser** & **Image uploader**